# Programmatically set SOAP binding 1.2 in java 1.4

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

Hi I have a Java Web service to call. The Web service is working on SOAP Binding 1.2.

Through Wizard of Oracle J-Developer(Oracle IDE 10.1.2.18.57), I have developed the Client from the WSDL file.

but the SOAP message being created is using SOAP Binding 1.1 Thus giving exception at call time.

I have Java 1.4 and i need to set the SOAP Binding to 1.2 programmatically.

please help if this can be done.

if not please provide some alternative to it.

Comment: Is this JAX-RPC? I believe it is limited to SOAP 1.1 - see [spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=101). JAX-WS which depends on Java 5 is required for SOAP 1.2. You may have to find some non-standard Java 1.4 SOAP 1.2 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some R&D, and the comment by McDowell is correct, i have to use Java 1.5 to do something like this. even to do it without annotations.

Thanks